# Do flash games work on all system platforms?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm developing a flash game using windows. But will these flash games actually work on linux and mac or do I need to work on something for that to be compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash requires a Flash Player to run. As long as the OS/Browser supports a Flash player, your program should run.
Most Operating systems (including linux and mac)  supports flash players.

Answer (score 1):

Flash is still very popular when it comes to games (outside web browser obviously).

You can pack your game with Adobe AIR, and it will run on all platforms, except Windows Phones(?). There's tons of native extensions and libraries available for example to get everything done with Android or iOS.

And yes; it runs on windows, mac and linux without Flash player.

Answer (score 0):

It will as long as you have a flash player.

Answer (score 0):

If the os or linux has installed flash player, the answer is yes.

But if you embed it in browser, and used parameters, you must write different HTML tag ( object/ embed).

see: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html

Answer (score -1):

It's way to late for a flash games.
You should go for java instead.

Or if it's simple serach for html5 games tutorial.

Got a minus so i'm going to answer widely.
No It's not. 
Android does not support flash.
Flash is leaky and has a secure issues.

Comment: That wasn't my question.